# Why does sumbitting a form for an AJAX request using "onchange" on an html element on Rails an "Authenticity Token" error?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to trigger an AJAX request using a select element in a form.  I use the "onchange" event on the select element simply to submit the form.  In addition, I have submit buttons within the form which also when clicked submit the form.

```
<%= form_tag contact_desc_path(@contact), remote: true,  :id => 'desc_form' do %>

    <%= select_tag :select, options_for_select(@contact.descriptions.order(:name).all.map{|description| [description.name, description.id]}, "") , {:onchange => 'desc_form.submit()'} %>

    <%= text_area_tag :desc, "", {class: "standard", style: "width:97%; height: 200px"} %>
    <%= submit_tag "Update" %>

<% end %>
```

Here (with the full code portion) is the resulting html

```
<form id="desc_form" action="/contact_desc/.291" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
    <table width=100%>
      <col width="20%">
      <col width="40%">
      <col width="20%">
      <col width="20%">
      <tr>
        <td class="standard_label">
          Select
        </td>
        <td>
           <select name="select" id="select" onchange="desc_form.submit()"><option value="7">Test1</option>
<option value="5">Test2</option>
<option value="6">Test6</option></select>

        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Delete" class="standard" style="width: 120px" data-disable-with="Delete" />
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="standard_label">
          Name
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Test1" class="standard" style="width:80%;" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Rename" class="standard" style="width: 120px" data-disable-with="Rename" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add" class="standard" style="width: 120px" data-disable-with="Add" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="standard_label">Description</div>
    <textarea name="desc" id="description" class="standard" style="width:97%; height: 200px">
```

The submit buttons work fine but using the select element gives the following server error

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken)

I have actually found a workaround by getting the select element to trigger a hidden submit button as below.

```
<%= form_tag contact_desc_path(@contact), remote: true,  :id => 'desc_form' do %>

    <%= select_tag :select, options_for_select( @contact.descriptions.order(:name).all.map{|description| [description.name, description.id]}, "") , {:onchange => '("select_button").click();'.html_safe } %>

    <div style="display: none">
        <%= submit_tag "Select", :id => "select_button", :style =>"width: 120px" %>
    </div>

    <%= text_area_tag :desc, "", {class: "standard", style: "width:97%; height: 200px"} %>
    <%= submit_tag "Update" %>

<% end %>
```

This works fine.

However, this is to say the least sub-optimally inelegant and I wondered if anyone knew why the select element submitting the form directly gave the InvalidAuthenticityToken error.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the final HTML, not RoR template code. Also add your JS code, because your AJAX code has to replicate submitting the form the standard way, and this will be exactly where the issue is. (btw, note that AJAX does *not* mean "submit the form programmatically", it means "submit the form in the background, without the browser navigating to the reply" because your current workaround doesn't mesh with the purpose of ajax)

Comment: Just speculating here, but the problem could be due to Rails UJS not catching the "submit" event. Your JS that processes the select event is "desc_form.submit()" which is a direct call on an element and is not producing an event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event `The event is not raised when calling the form.submit() method directly.` Short answer is: you might want to try `$(desc_form).submit()`

Comment: @Chris.  Thanks.  Full html now posted.  There is no JS over and above the onchange on the element.  Not sure I understand the point you raise in the last sentence.  I am seeking to submit the AJAZ request through a RoR form using remote.  I believe that is a perfectly respectable approach.  My workaround is simply to trigger the submit in an way which does not elicit the invalidity error.  I appreciate it is inelegant, hence my question.

Comment: @stepan.  Thanks also.  Ah ok.  Not sure I quite understand where Rails UJS starts and html ends in these situations but that explains it.

Comment: Actually @stepan, unfortunately $(desc_form).submit is no better.  It appears that Rails UJS is picking up neither desc_form.submit() nor $(desc_form).submit for this.  As I say above, I have a workaround but I am very open to finding a better way.

Comment: I see, a remote form means AJAX, that explains it. The only alternative I can see is to hand-write lots of AJAX code, so your workaround seems fine to me.